# CSS does not display background color for div tag

Tags: html, css

I put my div `id="banner"` and style it to give the color that matches the image but the color doesn't display. So, what should I do?

```css
#cloud {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
#page {
  width: 800px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
#home {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
#banner {
  background-color: #78c8f0;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="banner">
    <div id="cloud">
      <img src="Cloud4.gif" />
    </div>
    <!--cloud-->
    <div id="home">
      <h2>HOME</h2>
    </div>
    <!--home-->
  </div>
  <!--banner-->
</div>
<!--page-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply give `#banner` some height. See the snippet.

```
#banner {
  background-color: #78c8f0;
  height: 40px;
}
```

**Snippet**

```css
#cloud {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
#page {
  width: 800px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
#home {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
#banner {
  background-color: #78c8f0;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="banner">
    <div id="cloud">
      <img src="Cloud4.gif" />
    </div>
    <!--cloud-->

    <div id="home">
      <h2>HOME</h2>
    </div>
    <!--home-->
  </div>
  <!--banner-->
</div>
<!--page-->
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `#cloud` (the child of `#banner`) is floated, `#banner` essentially collapses and it acts like it doesn't have content. You can remedy this by adding `overflow:auto` to `#banner`.

```css
#cloud {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
#page {
  width: 800px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
#home {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
#banner {
  background-color: #78c8f0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="banner">
    <div id="cloud">
      <img src="Cloud4.gif" />
    </div>
    <!--cloud-->

    <div id="home">
      <h2>HOME</h2>
    </div>
    <!--home-->
  </div>
  <!--banner-->
</div>
<!--page-->
```

Answer (score 0):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/b6x3e29y/)

Th background colour was not shown because, the element which contained the content was floated and thus the other elements were such that it doesnt even exist. thus,

Either change your css for `#banner` as follows

```
#banner {
    float: left;
  background-color: #78c8f0;
}
```

OR

change your css for `#cloud` as follows

```
#cloud {
  /* float: left; */
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```